# How do I make functions run by g_idle_add/g_timeout_add work asynchronously?

Tags: c, user-interface, gtk

```
g_timeout_add (100, (GSourceFunc) read_next_packets, NULL);
```

I can feel the GUI response is slow because of the above statement.

How can I make it work asynchronously so that it doesn't affect the GUI response?

Answer (score 3):

Callbacks of these functions are called in the main thread.  If `read_next_packets` is slow or blocks for I/O, you should instead create a separate thread for it that doesn't interfere with GUI.  When that thread needs to inform the main thread of something, *then* it can use `g_idle_add` to transfer execution to the main thread scope.

In pseudocode:

```
// In a dedicated thread:
while (...) {
    Package*  package = do_read ();  // This call is slow or blocks.
    if (package)
        g_idle_add ((GSourceFunc) process_package, package);
}

// This is called in the main thread.  Should be fast to not freeze GUI.
gboolean
process_package (Package* package)
{
    ...
    package_free (package);
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to call a function in that **dedicated thread** from the main thread?

Comment: You can't directly.  Indirectly, you can establish a `GAsyncQueue` and make the thread process objects from that queue.  However, if all you need is a thread to read packages, just do that in a `while()` loop.